# Получение последней строки из базы данных sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Пользуюсь sqlite.

В базу данных постоянно добавляются строки (с помощью кода). Мне требуется получить последнюю записанную туда строку.

Как это сделать?

---

Дата добавления записи есть.

Comment: В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.

Comment: @KromStern, Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Если у вас есть например id записи который постоянно увеличивается или например дата добавления записи - то просто берете первую запись с обратной сортировкой по id (дате)

Comment: Дата добавления записи есть. А код для обратной сортировки подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DenShDen `SELECT smth FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: А если колонки с датой нет, то можно, как вариант, ещё и так: `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl)-1`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, пожалуйста, оформите комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 4):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Алексея Шиманского](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Выполните [запрос](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` к бд. Результатом будет запись, содержащая последний добавленный ID.

Если используется `autoincrement primary key` то можно воспользоваться вот таким запросом `select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="table_name"`. Вернет текущее значение инкремента, что и будем являться ключом на последнюю добавленную запись.

Comment: `last_insert_rowid()` возвращает последний id добавленный _в данной сессии_. В другой сессии, не делавшей insert данная функция ничего не даст.